# Why is definite article (the) used in this sentence?

Tags: articles, definite-articles

"**Global warming is the increase in the average temperature of the near-surface air and the oceans**."

I understand that the above sentence is the definition of global warming, so the nouns in this sentence such as (the) increase, (the) ... temperature, (the) ... air, and the oceans come with this definite article.
However, some of my friends argued that this is a general statement. So, those nouns should not be used with 'the'.

Could you please explain? Thank you.

Comment: There's no exception for not using definite articles in general statements. Your friends are probably thinking about the fact that we don't use definite articles when talking about nouns that refer to all things of some kind, like "foxes are red" and  "apples have seeds, but bananas don't".

Answer (score 1):

There's a 'backwards particularising' here. Take the phrase 'the increase'. *What* increase? It's specified as 'that increase *in the average temperature of* ...' (and in fact, 'that' could be used instead of 'the' here, but would be a rarefied usage). We say 'the Bay of Bengal', 'the crack of dawn', 'the Lord of the Rings', 'the man in the Moon', 'the man who shot Liberty Valance'. The specifier is the prepositional phrase (etc) postmodifying the head noun.

Similarly, *What* (or actually, *what*'s) average temperature? Again, this is soon specified.

The final two definite articles are obviously in parallel. One *could* omit these (omitting just the second would imply/emphasise that the near-surface air and oceans formed a cohesive system ... not actually incorrect, and omitting the first perhaps  hints too strongly at disparate entities), but 'the oceans' (and especially 'the Seven Seas') hint at a human ownership, and you'll often see the article with 'oceans' (and always with 'Seven Seas'). 'The oceans' also more strongly indicates *all* oceans.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am still a bit confused. For example, 'The oceans' indicates all oceans. Does this mean specification? But all oceans actually take general meaning?

Comment: 'The oceans' means (unless a subset has been mentioned) _all Earth's oceans (and possibly connected seas)_ in precise usage. 'Drake sailed across the oceans' obviously uses language more loosely. But in both cases, 'the' is used to show complete or partial specification.  I don't understand your final sentence, I'm afraid.

Comment: Sorry, I mean 'all oceans' is supposed to mean oceans in general. I understand that an indefinite article or a plural form should be used when we are talking about something in general. This article thing is quite confusing for EFL learners :(

Comment: Collins have written a 100+ page monograph on them, and it's far from complete.

Answer (score 0):

> the average temperature **of the near-surface air and the oceans**.

Firstly: it is a *very specific* average temperature. It is not "any" average temperature - it is a defined average temperature.

A/an  = an example of a/an , so it cannot be **an** average temperature - there are no more "average temperature**s** **of the near-surface air and the oceans**".

Temperature is a singular countable noun: In normal use as subjects and objects, all singular countable nouns require a determiner.

The choice must therefore be "the".